# Sql statement fetching information from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables, one of the table is called **participants_tb** while the second is called **allocation_tb**. On the **participants_tb**, I have my columns as **participant_id**, **name**, **username**. 
Under  the allocation_tb, I have my columns as **allocation_id**, **sender_username**, **receiver_username**, **done**. The column **done** holds any of these three numbers: 0, 1, 2.

I used this sql statement to fetch my values

```
SELECT *, COUNT(done) d
FROM participants_tb 
JOIN allocation_tb ON (username=receiver_username)
WHERE done = 0 || done = 1 
GROUP BY receiver_username
```

It worked very well, the problem I have is that, I want it to also include the information of participants that are in the participants_tb but not in the allocation_tb. I tried to use the **left outer join** but it did not work as expected because I want it to include participants that are only in the participants_tb but not in the allocation_tb, since the **done** in the where clause is in the allocation_tb, it won't include those information.

Comment: Considering that `||` isn't valid T-SQL, I've removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Alright, thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(a.done) as d
FROM participants_tb p LEFT JOIN
     allocation_tb a
     ON p.username = a.receiver_username) AND
        a.done IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY p.participant_id;
```

Notes:

- The `LEFT JOIN` keeps all participants.
- The `GROUP BY` needs to be on the first table.
- You can use `SELECT p.*` with the `GROUP BY` -- assuming that the `GROUP BY` key is unique (or the primary key).
- All columns should be qualified.
- `IN` is an easier way to express your logic.